# sqlite3 merge two tables fields into one, remove duplicates

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables which needs to be merged into one.
Tables have different number of rows.

```
table1
      att1     rel1

      1954WM   1699AC, 1847BC


table-2
      att2     rel2

      1954WM   1699AC, 1331, 1649A
      1499DD   1891, 9951A
```

Above is e.g. of structure.
What I would like to have is if table1.att1 == table-2.att2 then table1 would look like this:

```
table1
      att2     rel2

      1954WM   1699AC, 1847BC, 1331, 1649A
      1499DD   1891, 9951A
```

if theres no match for table-2.att2 in table1.att1 then add table-2.att2 with rel2 into table1.

Comment: First of all, it's not completely clear from how you format the data if the values are actually in a comma-separated string in the database or if this is your own shorthand notation for multiple rows.  If it represents rows, this is not a good short hand for representing database rows.  You should put each row of data on its own line even if you think this looks redundant.  The format of data is a critical part of a solution, so it is important to make this very clear.

Comment: @CPerkins - The Q you reference ("Merge two tables to one and remove duplicates") is not well-asked, and if you look at the comments, the intended question is different from the one asked here, so some of the answers there do not apply here.  So please don't close the question here: a clear answer here would be helpful to others as well.  Also, the questioner here is quite explicit about what is requested, i.e. the potential for confusion that you allude to is resolved within the Q.

Comment: is the `att2` column the primary key?

Answer (score 0):

**IF** you don't mind duplicate items in rel1 (i.e. merg duplicates refers to the att? columns) **AND IF** att1 column has a UNIQUE constraint then :-

```
WITH a AS(SELECT att1,rel1 FROM `table1` UNION SELECT att2 AS att1,rel2 AS rel1 FROM `table-2`),
         b AS (SELECT att1,group_concat(rel1) AS rel1 FROM a GROUP BY att1)          
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO `table1` SELECT att1,rel1 FROM b;
```

Will result in

[image]

**IF** you don't mind duplicate items in rel1 **BUT** the att1 column does not have a UNIQUE constraint then :-

```
WITH a AS(SELECT att1,rel1 FROM `table1` UNION SELECT att2 AS att1,rel2 AS rel1 FROM `table-2`),
         b AS (SELECT att1,group_concat(rel1) AS rel1 FROM a GROUP BY att1)          
INSERT INTO `table1` SELECT 'ADDED-'||att1,rel1 FROM b;

DELETE FROM `table1` WHERE instr(att1,'ADDED-') < 1;

UPDATE `table1` SET att1 = substr(att1,instr(att1,'ADDED-') + 1 + length('ADDED'));
```

or :-

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS att1ix ON `table1`(att1);
WITH a AS(SELECT att1,rel1 FROM `table1` UNION SELECT att2 AS att1,rel2 AS rel1 FROM `table-2`),
         b AS (SELECT att1,group_concat(rel1) AS rel1 FROM a GROUP BY att1)
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO `table1` SELECT att1,rel1 FROM b;
```

Will provide the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a side-effect-free SQL statement for computing the desired table:

```
WITH remnants AS (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE att1 NOT IN (SELECT att2 FROM table2))
SELECT * FROM (SELECT att1 as att2, rel1 as rel2 FROM remnants)
              UNION SELECT * FROM table2;
```

If you want to overwrite table1, you could use the following, but of course the result will retain the column names:

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE att1 IN (SELECT att2 FROM table2);
INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2;
```